# c++ this pointer doesn't execute the construct function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    int val;
    A(){
        val=0;
    }
    A( int n){
        val=n;
    }
    A GetObj(){
        return *this;
    }
};
main()  {
    A a;
    cout << a.val << endl;
    a.GetObj() = 5;
    cout << a.val << endl;
}
```

The output is 
    0
    0
But I want to implement
    0
    5
So how should I change the GetObj function?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure if it should even compile. But `a.GetObj()` returns a temporary that gets destroyed at the end of the expression.

Comment: You need to understand what `A::GetObj()` is actually returning when you call `a.GetObj()` before you'll fully understand why this doesn't work as-is. Hint: it isn't `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Now, `GetObj()` returns `A` by value, so it effectively returns a copy of `*this`. Returned object is not `a` - it's a totally new entity, created from `a`. To make it work, you would need to return it by reference:

```
A& GetObj(){
    return *this;
}
```

Best solution, however would be (IMHO) adding a setter for `val`:

```
class A {
public:
    //other things..

    void SetValue(int value) {
        this->val = value;
    }
};
```

And then:

```
a.SetValue(5);
```

Comment: He technically doesn't need to define the assignment operator as the compiler will use the `A(int)` constructor to convert the integer and then the call will match the implicit copy assignment operator which will perform the assignment.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah, yes, didn't notice that. Answer shortened a little bit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It follows an alternative approach which is nearest to what you are trying to achieve (`getObj` followed by the `=` symbol).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int val;
    A(){
        val=0;
    }
    A( int n){
        val=n;
    }
    A& operator=(int v) {
        val = v;
        return *this;
    }
};

main()  {
    A a;
    cout << a.val << endl;
    a = 5;
    cout << a.val << endl;
}
```